# Why is gnome-terminal slow when drawing characters with ncurses?

Tags: c, linux, ncurses, gnome-terminal

I've written a small program to compare ncurses performance between various terminal emulators and virtual console. I've found that gnome-terminal performs well in some situations, and poorly in others. When filling a fullscreen window with whitespace, it performs reasonably well. When filling the same area with full stops, it performs pretty bad. I've tried the same program using xterm and getty and both perform very well regardless of what character is being drawn.

My question is, what is going on with gnome-terminal? I'm also curious if can it be improved, or if I'm just doing something wrong here. And finally, is ncurses going to be the best performer for this kind of test in most cases? I ran a similar test changing colors with tput and drawing characters with printf, but its performance was much worse than ncurses.

Here is the source of the test program. It will run until interrupted, filling the screen with randomly colored squares containing either a blank space or a full stop.

```c
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  // Init ncurses.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  initscr();
  start_color();
  // Create color pairs for all combinations of standard colors.                                                                                                                                                   
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
      init_pair((i << 4) | j, i, j);
    }
  }
  // Loop forever. 
  while (1) {
    // Get current window dimensions.                                                                                                                                                                              
    int rows, cols;
    getmaxyx(stdscr, rows, cols);
    // Reset cursor.                                                                                                                                                                                               
    move(0, 0);
    // Loop rows.                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      // Loop columns.                                                                                                                                                                                             
      for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        // Set a random color pair.                                                                                                                                                                                
        attr_set(0, rand() % 0xff, NULL);
        // Draw a character.                                                                                                                                                                                       
        printw("."); // SLOW                                                                                                                                                                                       
        //printw(" "); // FAST                                                                                                                                                                                     
      }
    }
    // Draw.                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    refresh();
  }
  // Cleanup.                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Filling the whole screen with whitespace most probably only requires a few bytes (so it should be _very_ fast) while filling the whole screen with anything else requires repeating that character many times (unless there is some built in repeat-sequence that I don't know about). Measure the amount of output when filling the whole screen with spaces vs. any other character: `./program | tee prog.log` - check the size of `prog.log` afterwards.

Comment: The same number of bytes are being written in both cases. It's going to be the same as the area of the screen. Note that the whitespace case is not simply filling [rows] number of newlines, but instead filling the screen with [rows] * [cols] number of space (" ") characters.

Comment: Yes, but ncurses tends to be "smart" about it if I remember correctly. If it sees that the whole updated screen is full of spaces when you do `refresh()` it could just send the clear screen escape sequence instead of rows * cols spaces etc - but since you've verified that it's the same number of bytes that's being sent, that doesn't explain it.

Comment: That can't possibly be the case here. If you run the program, you will see that the individual colors are being drawn for every position on screen so there is no collapsing of rows happening.

Comment: I've checked it (and seeded rand with the same value to get the same values out) and limited the loop to two iterations. To my surprise, the _fast_ version sends 113 characters _more_ (slow: 361207 bytes, fast: 361320 bytes). So it's not the same number of bytes. One would have to investigate the escape sequences to figure out how it can be faster when it's sending more.

Comment: It _could_ be something with gnome itself that makes it noticably more expensive to render characters than blanks like you are suspecting. Does it make a difference if you do like this to change all outcoming `.`s to spaces? `./program | tr '.' ' '`

Comment: You should try again with different seed. I theorize that the color values selected (which are random) are what is leading to the discrepancy. I am certain that on some some seeds, fast will have more bytes and on other seeds, slow will have more bytes. Either way, I'm quite sure the byte count here is irrelevant to its performance.

Comment: Since I'm using the same seed in both the fast and slow version I get the same values from `rand()` in both cases so that doesn't explain why they don't send an equal amount of bytes. Does it make a difference if you run the slow version through `tr` like I showed?

Comment: Yes, Ted, and that pretty much confirms my suspicions. Piping into `tr` and dynamically changing the stream from ` ` to `.` causes a slowdown, and even on the flip side, changing `.` to ` ` causes a speedup.

Comment: Wow... crappy gnome-terminal :-)

Comment: Indeed. Also, I tried to confirm my theory and I found that it does seem to be the case. Depending on which seed you use, you will find that half the time slow will have more bytes and half the time fast will have more bytes. I realize that the color codes selected are going to be the same between runs using the same seed, however, the combination of code + character is going to influence the number of bytes that are written (for some reason).

Comment: Sure, if the same color is selected for two adjacent positions, it doesn't have to send that color code over the wire again.

Comment: How does that explain the discrepancy between the number of bytes written in fast vs slow using the same seed?

Comment: It doesn't explain that at all. You'd have to analyze the escape sequences to try to find an explanation for that as I mentioned. It does explain why the number of bytes sent varies with the seed though. There's a program called `aha`  which can convert the escape sequences to HTML which would make the analysis a bit easier: `TERM=ANSI ./program | aha > out.html`

Comment: _How_ do you measure performance? You run that app, and then what? Shouldn't it print some statistics when you quit, shouldn't it tell you how many bytes it printed? Or shouldn't you time how long it takes for the terminal to process a certain amount of data? (Also: what terminal window size, what font size, what compile flags, etc.?)

Comment: Also, what are the measurements on your system? How bad does gnome-terminal perform compared to xterm? Do you have numbers to show?

Comment: I've modified your test to run 1000 iterations only, and measured printing spaces vs dots. Repeated the test in xterm, vte 0.74 and brand new vte 0.76 (which received quite a few perf improvements). (vte is the engine behind gnome-terminal.) In all my tests, vte (gnome-terminal) was a little bit faster than xterm. So I cannot reproduce the slowness you're talking about. But I can confirm that handling a space is somewhat slower in vte than handling a dot.

Comment: What is the goal of your test? If you want to measure the thoughput of terminal emulators, then record your test app's output in a file and `cat` (or `dd` in large chunks) that file.

Comment: With a fullscreened window, identical font size in the two, ~320x80 cells, the gtk3 version of vte-0.76 is indeed slower than xterm on my computer, by a factor of about 2.5 (and vte-0.74 is even much slower). The gtk4 version (to be used by gnome-terminal in the near future) is faster. In other tests, e.g. consuming large input with a more reasonable amount of attribute changes, such as colored "ls" output, vte can easily be about 15x faster than xterm. Seems you've managed to find one scenario where vte is slower. Your conclusion: vte is crappy. Wow!

Comment: @egmont I am measuring performance with my eyes. It's visually very apparent that the slow program is filling the screen slower (less fps) than the fast program (more fps). If you're not able to visually see the difference then its possibly just an issue with gnome-terminal on my system, which is unfortunate.

Comment: "I'm also curious if can it be improved" - yes. Use the latest version, vte 0.76. Use its gtk4 version with (preview, unstable, work in progress!!!) gnome-terminal 3.97. If still not fast enough, dive into its code, optimize and send patches :)

Comment: @egmont Forgive me for being a little overly defensive here, but are you being sarcastic? My goal isn't to "expose" vte or gnome-terminal as being "crappy", but to find out why its performing slowly given a change that one might intuit as inconsequential. And possibly to find a way to improve it.

Comment: @JohnDriscoll Throughput and display update FPS are independent. I thought you primarily referred to throughput. vte 0.74 repaints the canvas at about 20-30 FPS. This was fixed in brand new crispy vte 0.76 which updates the display at 60 FPS (or whatever GTK's frame clock is). That is, assuming that 1/60 of a second is enough to paint the canvas, which might not be the case when a maximized window contains all different attributes. Then performance starts to regress heavily (in both vte and xterm).

Comment: @egmont Thanks, I will give 3.97 a try. I appreciate your investigation here.

Comment: Updating to stable vte 0.76 will help you a long way, give you 60Hz updates. If not enough, you might try unsable gnome-terminal 3.97 too, but don't be surprised if you run into usability issues that you may not like.

Answer (score 0):

ncurses will be "smart about" moving the cursor to points on the screen which should be updated (this is what ["cursor optimization"](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html) refers to, but the sample program simply walks through each cell on the screen, updating every cell in succession.

The cells differ by the colors — ncurses will notice if successive cells use the same color and refrain from sending color-changing escape sequences in that case (and some special cases of escape sequences are shorter), but otherwise the sample program provides no reason for ncurses to send fewer characters.

The performance issues are due to how fast gnome-terminal can handle changing colors on each cell of the screen — it's going to have a lot more bits per cell than just the 8 bits for "." and 8 bits for color.

Comment: I am dubious that is the case. As I discussed with Ted in the comments, the bytes the program will output has little to do with the character being output. Half the time, the "." (slow) program outputs *less* bytes than the " " (fast) program. Your answer suggests that gnome-terminal's color changing performance is dependent on the amount of bits being output. If that were the case, half the time the slow program would be the fast program.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in the comments, the claimed slowness of GNOME Terminal was perceived with the naked eye, as in the display prominently updating less frequently.

This is true. VTE (the terminal emulation engine behind GNOME Terminal and several other terminal apps) up until now used to update its display around maybe 20-30 times per second.

Brand new VTE 0.76 fixes this problem and updates the display according to the GTK frame clock (which is synchronized to the monitor's refresh cycles), i.e. typically 60 times per second, resulting in a much smoother experience.

This barely (if at all) correlates with throughput, i.e. the amount of data processed in a given time. The fact that a terminal updates its display less frequently does not say anything about its speed in consuming large amounts of incoming data.

Comment: Well said and much appreciated

Comment: An additional note about throughput: Both xterm and vte, at 80x24-ish size (i.e. updating the display only takes a small amount of time) process 1000 full screen ncurses repaints of the example code in around 4-8 seconds on my computer. This corresponds to 125-250 Hz. With fewer attribute changes it could be even much bigger. That is, by far not every piece of incoming data makes it into display pixels, most of them are skipped and never painted.